# Почему не выводятся данные из базового примера vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Копирую [пример](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/data-tables#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B), и с [быстрым стартом](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/getting-started/quick-start#-cdn) хочу посмотреть, как это работает. Таблица выводится, а данные нет. В чём проблема?

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        expand: false,
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name'
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%'
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%'
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          item-key="name"
          show-expand
          :single-expand="expand"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <template #top>
            <v-toolbar flat color="white">
              <v-toolbar-title>Expandable Table</v-toolbar-title>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="expand = !expand">
                {{ expand ? 'Close' : 'Keep' }} other rows
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
          <template #item.expanded="{ headers }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">Peek-a-boo!</td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Во-первых `[Vuetify] Vuetify requires Vue version ^2.5.18`

Comment: @NikitaUmnov я видел, но не в этом проблема. Сейчас так подключу.

Comment: @dook911 Код не соответствует примеру https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/data-tables. В примере все работает. У вас, например, пропущены `v-slot` у `template`

Comment: @NikitaUmnov где в конкретном примере `v-slot` https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010? Почему на codepen работает всё без `v-slot`?

Comment: @dook911 какой конкретно пример здесь https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/data-tables? Не могу там ваш найти а ссылка на codepen не работает

Comment: @NikitaUmnov https://next.vuetifyjs.com/ru/components/data-tables#slot-expand

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91473/discussion-between-doox911-and-nikita-umnov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить скрипт:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

На скрипт из примера

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

И определить экземпляр Vuetify

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
      return {
          expand: false,
          headers: [
              {
                  text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                  align: 'left',
                  sortable: false,
                  value: 'name'
              },
              { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
              { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
              { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
              { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
              { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
          ],
          desserts: [
              {
                  name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                  calories: 159,
                  fat: 6.0,
                  carbs: 24,
                  protein: 4.0,
                  iron: '1%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                  calories: 237,
                  fat: 9.0,
                  carbs: 37,
                  protein: 4.3,
                  iron: '1%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Eclair',
                  calories: 262,
                  fat: 16.0,
                  carbs: 23,
                  protein: 6.0,
                  iron: '7%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Cupcake',
                  calories: 305,
                  fat: 3.7,
                  carbs: 67,
                  protein: 4.3,
                  iron: '8%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Gingerbread',
                  calories: 356,
                  fat: 16.0,
                  carbs: 49,
                  protein: 3.9,
                  iron: '16%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Jelly bean',
                  calories: 375,
                  fat: 0.0,
                  carbs: 94,
                  protein: 0.0,
                  iron: '0%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Lollipop',
                  calories: 392,
                  fat: 0.2,
                  carbs: 98,
                  protein: 0,
                  iron: '2%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Honeycomb',
                  calories: 408,
                  fat: 3.2,
                  carbs: 87,
                  protein: 6.5,
                  iron: '45%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'Donut',
                  calories: 452,
                  fat: 25.0,
                  carbs: 51,
                  protein: 4.9,
                  iron: '22%'
              },
              {
                  name: 'KitKat',
                  calories: 518,
                  fat: 26.0,
                  carbs: 65,
                  protein: 7,
                  iron: '6%'
              }
          ]
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          item-key="name"
          show-expand
          :single-expand="expand"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <template #top>
            <v-toolbar flat color="white">
              <v-toolbar-title>Expandable Table</v-toolbar-title>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="expand = !expand">
                {{ expand ? 'Close' : 'Keep' }} other rows
              </v-btn>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
          <template #item.expanded="{ headers }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">Peek-a-boo!</td>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.0-alpha.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я так и делал с самого начала. Но получаю ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Vuetify is not a constructor
    at test.html:40`

Comment: Замени скрипт подключения vuetify как я написал. Там версия другая